# Parse Data vs Parse Cloud Code tab

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cloud

I have a fast question. I've been using Parse database to save data to be used on my app.

Cloud code tab is useful for what? Please, give me a 2line example, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud code is where you put heavier processing that should not be performed on your client, for performance reasons. You can also use cloud code for adding processing on events like afterSave(), beforeSave() etc

Answer (score 0):

Cloud code is basically custom code that you can run into their Parse server. I use it to resize images with the afterSave() event that they provide.

A basic code example would be:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("helloWorld", function(request, response) {
    response.success("helloWorld!");
});
```